# netbeans: bundle files to nbm

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

This Question refers to [How to bundle additional (data) files with a Netbeans module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173469/how-to-bundle-additional-data-files-with-a-netbeans-module).
I have two Pyhtonscripts, which I want to integrate in the created NBM, so they can be executed from within the plugin.

I tried all the solutions from the Question above (except the Maven part), as well as putting the files in every possible location inside the project, but it had no influence.

I think the last part of [this](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projectsamples.html) tutorial -"Updating the Sources"- would do the trick. Am I on the right path? I did include the code in my build-init.xml, but (I don't know if I set the Locations right) there was no improvement at all.

Comment: Its been a couple of years since I left Ant behind me but are you really sure it doesn't help to put your script files in your `src` directory ? In any case an NBM is nothing but a jar file with a bit of extras. You can look inside the NBM you've created by either using the IDE itself or by using an external archiver tool such as 7Zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already posted the link to the right thread:
2nd answer is for maven,
3rd and accepted answer is for ant: just create a subdirectory called "release" in your module project. You can then get the File via InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate(...).
To get "release/something.txt" you would call
locate("something.txt", "your.module", false)

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for modules that are using maven

1. Create a netbeans module
2. create folder name it as "release" under the `src/main`
3. Add scripts to the release folder
4. Then edit that module POM, under the plugin section in nbm-maven-plugin add below code

   > ```
   > <configuration>
   >          <moduleDependencies>
   >               <dependency>
   >                    <id>org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seplatform</id>
   >                    <type>impl</type>
   >                    <explicitValue>org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform/1=${netbeans.impl.version}</explicitValue>
   >                             </dependency>
   >                         </moduleDependencies>
   >                         <nbmResources>
   >                             <nbmResource>
   >                                 <directory>src/main/release</directory>
   >                             </nbmResource>
   >                         </nbmResources>
   >                         <publicPackages>
   >                             <publicPackage>com.dev.api</publicPackage>
   >                         </publicPackages>
   >                     </configuration>
   > ```
5. Build that module
6. you can call the file using `File file = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate("scriptName.cmd", "com.dev.api", false)`
7. If you are using in a different module you can add dependency of the module that contains the scripts